# Hadoop Setup: No Permission to create Directories when Hadoop folder is owned by user

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am following this tutorial (currently 2.7.2) https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html on an earlier (2.0.0alpha) version of Hadoop on Ubuntu 14.04.4.

however, running `sbin/start-dfs.sh`  after formatting namenode gives the following error:

```
17/01/06 11:46:20 WARN util.KerberosName: Kerberos krb5 configuration not found, setting default realm to empty
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/username’: Permission denied
localhost: chown: cannot access ‘/username/username’: No such file or directory
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /username/username/hadoop-username-namenode-hostname.out
localhost: /home/username/project/hadoop/hadoop-dist/target/hadoop-2.0.0-alpha/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 149: /username/username/hadoop-username-namenode-hostname.out: No such file or directory
localhost: head: cannot open ‘/username/username/hadoop-username-namenode-hostname.out’ for reading: No such file or directory
localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/username’: Permission denied
localhost: chown: cannot access ‘/username/username’: No such file or directory
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /username/username/hadoop-username-datanode-hostname.out
localhost: /home/username/project/hadoop/hadoop-dist/target/hadoop-2.0.0-alpha/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 149: /username/username/hadoop-username-datanode-hostname.out: No such file or directory
localhost: head: cannot open ‘/username/username/hadoop-username-datanode-hostname.out’ for reading: No such file or directory
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/username’: Permission denied
0.0.0.0: chown: cannot access ‘/username/username’: No such file or directory
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /username/username/hadoop-username-secondarynamenode-hostname.out
0.0.0.0: /home/username/project/hadoop/hadoop-dist/target/hadoop-2.0.0-alpha/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 149: /username/username/hadoop-username-secondarynamenode-hostname.out: No such file or directory
0.0.0.0: head: cannot open ‘/username/username/hadoop-username-secondarynamenode-hostname.out’ for reading: No such file or directory
```

I have seen many [other posts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37786/permission-denied-errors-whe-starting-a-single-node-cluster-in-hadoop) about changing the owner, but I didn't create a special user for hadoop, so sshing into localhost still shows the user as my "username". Obviously then the hadoop folder is owned by me, and I actually ran chown just to make sure as well, so why is there still a permission issue here?